# QGIS Server [Map request failed error: Host _ not found]

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server

I am trying to set up a QGIS Server to publish the WMS layer using a docker container.

I followed the following section in the QGIS Manual https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/containerized_deployment.html#docker-stacks

Based on this I was able to see this page successfully using the following url and it looked like that everything had been set up correctly. http://localhost:8080/qgis-server/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

[image]

I was also able to add the WMS connection and see layers in QGIS Browser like this
[image]

But when I try to load this layer in the canvas I get the following error

[image]

I tried publishing the GeoJson Polygon layer by adding it to the source QGIS project but it was giving the same error as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that Example map in QGIS training manual is missing Advertised URL for both WMS and WFS. Add them like this and QGIS will be able to load both WFS and WMS in Canvas.

[image]